why is \tag not working in amsmath?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$$x\tag{1}$$

\end{document}

Here, it only outputs x in the center. the \tag is not working. Overleaf is shouting "\tag is not allowed in amsmath." Why is that case?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

$$ is not a supported LaTeX command, use an amsmath display environment such as \begin{equation*}..

\tag is one of an amsmath command and it should works only in the respective environments like align, equaion, and gather etc. $$...$$ is a PlainTeX command, hence \tag should not work
